# Windows 10 NTP polling time

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, time

I am doing some research about the Windows Time service on Windows 10 devices. I was looking at the default polling time and found ([1](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/121/windows-10-internet-time.html), [2](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-internet-time-update-interval-windows), [3](https://timetoolsltd.com/time-sync/configuring-a-windows-time-server/)) that by default, it polls once a week.
This seems like an extremely long period compared to `timesyncd` (used on Ubuntu for example). The `timesyncd` daemon uses a default max poll interval of just 2048 seconds.

Is there a reason for this long polling interval or did I misinterpret the information? I understand that a higher polling rate might decrease battery life and increase utilisation of the resources, but moderately new systems should be fine syncing a few times a day.

In my tests, Windows 10 device clock offsets were on average a fair amount greater than on Ubuntu devices.

Side question: Do OEMs in general change this default polling value for optimization?

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't matter?

Comment: @user253751 Maybe, but maybe it does. I'm looking for a solid explanation as to way the difference are so big. I saw clock offsets of 30sec on recent Windows 10 systems. This is huge and I'm looking into why that is.